# Importing Libraries on Android Studio like on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I just started using Android Studio actively last month and I have really worked hard to learn my way around it. Apart from a lot of different shortcuts here and there something is giving me headache. Do I really have to know every library to set up my project error free?

Now after copying code from SO I just can't find how to add the import libraries. On Eclipse the compiler when it shouted of a missing library, a simple hover on the error line was all I needed to fix the missing library since a context menu often revealed suggestions of the missing library.

For instance, if I add the code:

```
Private Locale locale;
```

The compiler will say:

> error: cannot find symbol class Locale

How do I solve such an issue without having to which class or library needs to be imported here? By the way, I have no problem importing Eclipse projects to Android Studio.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Clicking on red line, then pressing Alt + Enter.
2. Enabling Auto Imports from settings

None of them seem to be working at all. As I wait for help I have to google whatever library I really need to import to my class.

Comment: You can directly export your project for android studio from eclipse

Comment: I think you never understood my question at all. Am talking of code and not a whole project.

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: have you tried this import java.util.Locale;

Comment: That was just an example among many problems i need to solve

Comment: I think he wants to be import them automatically like we do on eclipse.